# C1Chart and custom field in C1ReportDesigner

Tags: charts, report, reportviewer, report-designer

I am getting an error: "Failed to create custom field 'C1.C1Report.CustomFields.Chart’ from assembly 'c1.c1report.customfields.4′."

I am using ComponentOne Studio for ASPNET_2011

I have troubleshoot almost everything that were suggested in the forum.

I am creating a Report Defination(xml) template using C1ReportDesigner. The Report defination contains some subreports and Custom Filed for Chart. The report works fine with the C1ReportDesigner Preview, but when I am using the same template in web forms 4.0 using C1ReportViewer it givers me the above mentioned error. Without CustomField (Chart) it won’t gives me error.

I have mentioned the versions of the dll’s below:

C1ReportDesigner Details

> Designer Version: 4.6.20111.54308 C1Report Version: 4.6.20111.54308
>   C1.C1Report.CustomFields.4.dll —–> 4.6.20101.1 C1.C1Report.4.dll —–>
>   4.6.20111.54308 (\ComponentOne\Studio for ASP.NET\ReportingTools\Designer.4) C1.C1Report.4.dll —–>
>   4.6.20111.54307 (\ComponentOne\Studio for ASP.NET\bin\v4) C1.Win.C1Chart.4.dll —-> 4.0.20101.20119 (\ComponentOne\Studio for
>   ASP.NET\ReportingTools\Designer.4
>
> WebApplication(Project) Dll’s
>
> //C1.C1Report.4.dll —–> 4.6.20111.54307
>   //C1.C1Report.CustomFields.4.dll —–> 4.6.20101.1
>   //C1.Win.C1Chart.4.dll —> 4.0.20111.21027

I have added the Custom Field dll in the project as suggested in the forum but its not working. Please help!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be due to incorrect version of the chart dll used.

The CustomField dll used is of 10v1 while the version of the C1Chart dll is 11v1 (ie. a later one).

Hence, adding the references of the latest versions of the C1Chart won’t serve the purpose as the CustomFields dll would not be able to refer to this chart dll. You need to add the dll(s) of the version of controls that come packaged with the C1ReportDesigner and are in sync with the version of the dll used by the CustomField project.

You may refer to the following forum post for the complete detail/information on this :
http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/failed-to-create-custom-field-c1-c1report-customfields-chart/

Regards,
Mohita